# show deleted record show on vfpage which are existing in recycle bin

Tags: soql, recycle-bin

I have 10 Contact which are showing in my vfpage..suppose i'll delete 3 record then its show only 7 record on vfpage. i want to also show deleted record which was gone into recyclebin. what is the soql query or any keyword to show deleted record data on tha vfpage

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your Query Append with **`ALL ROWS`**. It will include the Deleted Records too...

Like below Query

```
[SELECT COUNT() FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = a.Id ALL ROWS]
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `ALL ROWS` keyword in SOQL.

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_query_all_rows.htm)

```
[SELECT COUNT() FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = a.Id ALL ROWS]
```

**To retrieve only deleted records**

```
[SELECT COUNT() FROM Contact WHERE isDeleted=True ALL ROWS]
```

**Note:**

1. `ALL ROWS` keyword seems to work perfectly with apex code(Or maybe with [Workbench](http://workbench.developerforce.com)) but not in query editor(Developer console)
2. These queries returns the rows which are even deleted from recycle bin(For a limited time period) too so keep that in mind.

Comment: Might be worth explaining how to *only* query deleted rows for completeness.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Done :)

Answer (score 2):

To query items that are in the recycle bin, just construct a query on any object where `IsDeleted=1`. Like for querying deleted reports you can write a query like this - `[SELECT Id,Name FROM Account WHERE IsDeleted = true]`.

Please refer to this link from Salesforce for more details. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-to-retrieve-my-records-and-data-that-has-been-lost-or-deleted-1327108681812&language=en_US

Comment: i tried its showing  Unknown error parsing query

Comment: Can we have both Isdeleted=true and ALL ROWS??

Comment: Hi Vipin and Javanoob, I have updated my answer and removed the ALL ROWS.  I have also mentioned the Salesforce doc that I referred.